# What does the CSS “.x-data .x-time span” mean?

Tags: css

What does the following CSS syntax mean?

```css
.x-data .x-time span
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it is  a selector for a span that resides in a div (or anything) with class .x-time, which inturn is nested inside a class .x-data

for example, if you had the css like:

```
.x-data .x-time span {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: red;
}
```

and then a structure like this:

```
<div class="x-data">
    <div class="x-time">
        Time: <span>12:00</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

then the 12:00 is going to be in font size 12, and in red. where as "Time:" part is just going to follow the inherited format.

Answer (score 6):

It targets the span elements inside elements with class "x-time", which, themselves, are also inside element with class="x-data".

Answer (score 3):

> Selects any span element  that is a descendant of any element with a class attribute that contains the word x-time  that is a descendant of any element with a class attribute that contains the word x-data.

via [SelectOracle](http://penguin.theopalgroup.com/cgi-bin/css3explainer/selectoracle.py). I recommend giving [Selectutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/) a read too.

Answer (score 1):

its like saying Donkey's Tail's Hair.

so .x-data will be donkey
.x-time will be tail
span will be hair!!

so .x-data's .x-time's span.

get it?

Answer (score -1):

any element with a class of '.x-data' containing any element with a class of '.x-time' containing any `<span>` will be styled.

eg.

```
<p class="x-data">
    lipsum
    <span class="x-time">
        <span>lipsum</span> <!-- only this guy is styled -->
        <strong>sdadsa</strong>
    </span>
    <span>dolor</span>
</p>
```

Comment: That's backwards, it's a descendent selector, not an ancestor selector :)

Comment: may be just his structure is mixed up, this looks like the element is targetted, where as, i am sure he meant it to be span...

Comment: @Noon Silk - this is wrong because it's not the element with a class of `x-data` that gets selected, it's the `span`.

Comment: @David: sorry mate, you're wrong! I just added a code sample to explain it better. Its definitely not backwards they way I explained it first. Also I realise now that SO's textarea simply ate up my span because i didnt do the inline tilde character

Comment: Your example is correct but your description implies it is the element with the class 'x-data' that is going to be targeted.

Comment: omg, what is with the way I've explained it that you guys find hard to read and understand? It's not wrong!

Comment: well, when so many people are saying its wrong, there has to be something to it right? look at your sentence, it says: "any element with (...) will be targeted". In plain English, it means that the element is targeted. Sorry for picking up on you but I am just doing it so you will realize and not repeat this same thing again.

Comment: @iamserious: I think I see it now. I've replaced targetted with styled. The targeted is referring  to the first element .xdata which was wrong